# How to explode ignoring whit space without using regular expression

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
<?php
$text = "A Beauti f u l Bird";
$arr = explode("Beautiful", $text);
echo $arr[0];

?>
```

My expected output **A**

Comment: read [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: it would be best to use [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Comment: $text = str_replace(" ", "", $text); => it will remove all the white spaces

Answer (score 0):

PHP considers the following characters to be whitespace:

- The space character (" ")
- The tab character ("\t")
- The vertical tab character ("\v")
- The newline character ("\n")
- The carriage return character ("\r")
- The null-byte character ("\x0B")

We can remove all these whitespaces inside a string using [strtr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) function.

```
<?php
$text = "A Beauti f u l Bird";
$translate = array(" " => "", "\n" => "", "\t" => "", "\v" => "", "\r" => "", "\x0B" => "");
$text = strtr($text, $translate);
$arr = explode("Beautiful", $text);
echo $arr[0];
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove all spaces you can use the str_replace() function before using explode:

```
$text = "A Beauti f u l Bird";
$text = str_replace(" ", "", $text);
$arr = explode("Beautiful", $text);
echo $arr[0]; // "A"
```

This does not include whitespace characters, including newlines, carriage returns and tabs.

Comment: trim only remove at the begining and the end of the string.

Comment: @svgta you're correct, I've adjusted the answer. Thanks!